# Swapping list prefix and suffix in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I would like to make a program that swaps suffix and prefix of lists.
This is expected result.

```
?- swap([a,b,c,d,e],[c,d],Xs).
Xs = [e,c,d,a,b] ;
false.
```

I am trying to solve it using a 4-tuple predicate with accumulator prefix.

```
swapPrefixSuffix(L, SL, R) :-
   swapPrefixSuffix(SL, L, R, Prefix).

swapPrefixSuffix(SL, L, R, []) :-
   append(SL,[_|_], L),
   Prefix = [],
   append(SL,Prefix,R).
swapPrefixSuffix(SL, [A|L], R, [A|Prefix]) :-
   swapPrefixSuffix(SL, L, R, Prefix).
```

This is what I have so far...

Comment: And why are you not happy with it?

Comment: because it doesn't work

Comment: Please define *doesn't work*. What's the expected result? Your result looks correct. If you're talking about the `fail` after the result, that's normal Prolog behavior, indicating that there was a choice point left after the first solution, but no further solutions were found. You need to explain what doesn't work. Error message? Something else?

Comment: The result I wrote is the expected result. The code I got so far doesn't give me the what I expected.

Comment: What does it give you?

Comment: Are you using SWI Prolog? If so, then use the `append/2` predicate rather than `append/3`. It will be very easy then.

Comment: It gives me d = [c,d]... I will try with append/2.

Comment: I got the working code. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to write recursive code—use the predefined predicates [`append/3`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append) and [`same_length/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dlists.html#index-same_005flength_002f_005b2_002c3_005d-_0028lists_0029-1)!

```
:- use_module(library(lists),[append/3,same_length/2]).

swap(XYZ,Y,ZYX) :-
   same_length(XYZ,ZYX),
   append(X,YZ,XYZ),
   append(Y,Z,YZ),
   append(Z,Y,ZY),
   append(ZY,X,ZYX).
```

Sample queries using [SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/) 4.3.2:

```
?- swap([a,b,c,d,e],[c,d],Xs).
  Xs = [e,c,d,a,b]                    % as given by the OP
; false.

?- swap(Xs,[c,d],[e,c,d,a,b]).
  Xs = [a,b,c,d,e]                    % works in the "other direction", too!
; false.
```

How about a more general query?

```
?- XYZ=[_,_,_|_], Y=[_], swap(XYZ,Y,ZYX).
  XYZ = [_A,_B,_C]   , Y = [_A], ZYX = [_B,_C,_A]
; XYZ = [_A,_B,_C]   , Y = [_B], ZYX = [_C,_B,_A]
; XYZ = [_A,_B,_C]   , Y = [_C], ZYX = [_C,_A,_B]
; XYZ = [_A,_B,_C,_D], Y = [_A], ZYX = [_B,_C,_D,_A]
; XYZ = [_A,_B,_C,_D], Y = [_B], ZYX = [_C,_D,_B,_A]
; XYZ = [_A,_B,_C,_D], Y = [_C], ZYX = [_D,_C,_A,_B]
; XYZ = [_A,_B,_C,_D], Y = [_D], ZYX = [_D,_A,_B,_C]
...
```